# How to route a stepper motor through an H-bridge and back into an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, h-bridge

So I’ve gone and tried connecting the VCC and GND of a six lead stepper motor (just the two) to the BTS7960 H-bridge, and through that connected to my numbered 0-n pins for I/O on the Arduino Leonardo.

The only problem is I’m not quite sure if I’m following correctly because I have a few options and none are working at least for me.

I see it’s says use pins in case:

- 1pwm+1dir

Or

- 1pwm+2dir etc

I’m not 100% sure if I’m supposed to use any leads other than the  VCC or GND from the motor, because the stepper motor didn’t come with an encoder I had to buy one separately and get that one working.

As of now I’m just connecting:

- L_EN > pin 8
- R_EN > pin 11
- LPWM > pin 9

In case of: 1 PWM + 2DIR

- Pin 9 for PWM
- Pin 8 for DIR L
- pin 11 for DIR R

I’m connecting this through the Arduino Leonardo and just need to know whether or not I messed something up considering the six leads on the motor.

Just to be clear, a one motor set up with two directions is 1PWM 2DIR correct? I tried looking it up but all I got was definitive answers for the methods of how they work but not what they are in terms of application.

Comment: Can you draw schemtics of what you are talking about? "Through" an Arduino doesn't mean anything to me in this context.

Comment: BTS 7960 is not an H bridge. It takes two of those IC's to make an H bridge. Look at Application Data Sheet page 22 Rev. 1.1, 2004-12-076 Figure 11 Application Note

Answer (score 1):

[image]  Ref: http://www.orientalmotor.com/stepper-motors/technology/

You have a 6 lead motor designed for unipolar Nch switches, yet you are using a bipolar half-bridge IC. (BTS 7960 is not an H bridge.)

Change drivers to a dual half-bridge with V+ on both centre taps
or change the motor wiring to a 4 lead bipolar and H bridge driver for each coil.